# Keyboardに合わせて、Viewを移動させたい！

Tags: xcode, swift3

Keyboardに合わせて、Viewを移動させるアニメーションがうまくいきません。
画像①~③のようにtextFieldをクリックした後にKeyboardが表示され、その上にViewが移動し表示されるのですが、Keyboardが表示されてから遅れてViewが移動してきます。
また、Keyboardの文字を入力すると予測変換でViewが隠れてしまいます。
原因の分かる方はアドバイスいただけると助かります。
①
[image: ①]
②
[image: ②]
③
[image: ③]

ソースは以下のようになっています。

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(true)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(handleKeyboardWillShowNotification), name: Notification.Name.UIKeyboardDidShow, object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(handleKeybordWillHideNotification), name: Notification.Name.UIKeyboardDidHide, object: nil)
}

func handleKeyboardWillShowNotification(_ notification: Notification){
    let keyboardFrame = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue
    let duration = notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey]

    UIView.animate(withDuration: duration as! TimeInterval, animations: {
        //self.view.frame.origin.y = -(keyboardFrame?.height)!
        let transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: -(keyboardFrame?.size.height)!)
        self.view.transform = transform
        //self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    },completion:nil)
}

func handleKeybordWillHideNotification(_ notification: Notification){
    let duration = notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] as! Double
    UIView.animate(withDuration: duration, animations: {
        //self.view.frame.origin.y = 0
        let transform = CGAffineTransform (translationX: 0, y: 0)
        self.view.transform = transform
        //self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    },completion:nil)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> Keyboardが表示されてから遅れてViewが移動してきます。

以下のように、受け取るNotificationを変更することで、解決するようです。

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(true)
    // Notification.Name.UIKeyboardDidShow -> .UIKeyboardWillShow
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(handleKeyboardWillShowNotification), name: Notification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
    // Notification.Name.UIKeyboardDidHide -> UIKeyboardWillHide
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(handleKeybordWillHideNotification), name: Notification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)
}
```

> Keyboardの文字を入力すると予測変換でViewが隠れてしまいます。

これも、受け取ったNotificationから取得する情報を変更すればいいようです。

```
func handleKeyboardWillShowNotification(_ notification: Notification){
    // UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey -> UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey
    let keyboardFrame = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue
    let duration = notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey]

    UIView.animate(withDuration: duration as! TimeInterval, animations: {
        let transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: -(keyboardFrame?.size.height)!)
        self.view.transform = transform
    },completion:nil)
}
```

イベントが起きる前と、起きた後のNotification、NotificationのInfoを、どう採用するかで、細かな挙動が変化するのですね。
以下、変更をまとめておきました。

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(true)

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(ViewController.handleKeyboardWillShowNotification(_:)), name: .UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(ViewController.handleKeybordWillHideNotification(_:)), name: .UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)
}

override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidDisappear(animated)

    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: .UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: .UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)
}

func handleKeyboardWillShowNotification(_ notification: Notification){
    guard let keyboardFrame = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue,
        let duration = notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] as? TimeInterval else {
            return
    }

    UIView.animate(withDuration: duration, animations: {
        let transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: -(keyboardFrame.size.height))
        self.view.transform = transform
    }, completion: nil)
}

func handleKeybordWillHideNotification(_ notification: Notification){
    guard let duration = notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] as? Double else {
        return
    }

    UIView.animate(withDuration: duration, animations: {
        let transform = CGAffineTransform (translationX: 0, y: 0)
        self.view.transform = transform
    }, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: 受け取るNotificationによってここまで挙動が変わることを初めて知りました。Notificationについてもっと勉強しようと思います。指摘された通り、直したところうまく動きました！有難うございました。